# Python: how to tell if number strings mixed European or US format, cast all of them to float?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I want to convert all of the numbers in my list to float.

Every number contains 2 or 3 decimal places.

In some cases, I may have US number strings, such as:

```
"0.00", "0.000", "874.80", "10.000", "1,234.56"
```

In other cases, I may have European format, like the following:

```
"29.461,24", "20.919,000", "0,00", "0,000", "372,13", "11,000"
```

I want to identify which one is which and format it correctly to be cast to float. Such as the US numbers becoming.

```
"0.00", "0.000", "874.80", "10.000", "1234.56"
```

and the EU numbers becoming

```
"29461.24", "20919.000", "0.00", "0.000", "372.13", "11.000"
```

How can I do this in Python?

I know that

```
sub(r'[\.|]', '', sub(r',', '.', i))
```

Converts from E to a ready to cast format, but it will break US numbers.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: which format is `123,456`? (if you can have three places behind the decimal point per your second number..)

Comment: There isn't really a good way to tell. For example ````1,000```` is that ````1```` in European style or ````1000```` in US style?

Comment: I added my expected output, thank you for the reminder.

Comment: 123,456 is US format.

Comment: If you can have more than 2 digits after the decimal, this is not possible unless you know ahead of time which strings are US and EU.

Comment: Why is 123,456 US format?

Comment: @JeremyBarnes, at the moment this should be considered as custom replacement, but not as unified format identifying

Comment: Its actually 1,234.56

Comment: Do you have a way of determining which ones are US/EU?

Comment: Nope! But in my source data, every number DOES have at least two decimal places.

Comment: @JeremyBarnes So it's guaranteed to have the proper decimal separator? Then it is probably doable. Does order need to be maintained?

Comment: Order absolutely needs to be maintained. The correct decimal seperators are guaranteed.

Comment: is the input a raw string or it's a list of words?

Comment: List of words, like
["0.00", "0.000", "874.80", "10.000", "1,234.56"]

Comment: pure regex, I think this works: `(?:\d{0,3},?)+\.(\d{2,3})(?![\d,])|(?:\d{0,3}\.?)+\,(\d{2,3})(?![\d\.])` [example](https://regex101.com/r/0E9lyU/1) Can someone else confirm or minimize? If it is US the decimal will appear in Group 1, if it is EU the decimal will appear in Group 2

Comment: @jjspace that looks fine to me, although you still have to strip the punctuation off the whole numbers afterwards. Might even end up cleaner than my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note for future viewers**: This **requires** that "the correct decimal seperators are guaranteed."

If your data set contains numbers without decimal (US`1,000`), this **will not work**.

This will parse a list:

```
def mixed_to_float(lst):
    result = []
    for element in lst:
        if isUS(element):
            result.append(float(''.join(element.split(','))))
        else:
            num, dec = element.split(',')
            result.append(float(''.join(num.split('.')) + '.' + dec))
    return result
```

Uses the first `,` or `.` from the end to determine if US or EU:

```
def isUS(string):
    for char in string[::-1]:
        if char in ".,":
            return char == '.'
    raise ValueError("String does not have a decimal separator")
```

Result:

```
>>> mixed_to_float(["1.23", "1,923.23", "1,123", "1.231,423"])
[1.23, 1923.23, 1.123, 1231.423]
```

Comment: Something like `"1,123"` is ambiguous though

Comment: @ryugie normally, that would be true. The OP said, however, that for his data "The correct decimal seperators are guaranteed." I'll add a note :)

Answer (score 1):

In the general case this can't be done. But with your particular constraints, where you know each number will have a decimal point, it becomes possible. You can use a regular expression to check for EU numbers where `.` is followed by `,`.

```
import re
re_EU = re.compile('\\.[0-9]*,')
if any(re_EU.search(num) for num in numbers):
    // convert to US format
```

Comment: This regex won't catch `"1,234"` which should end up as `"1.234"`... that being said, checking for a `,` with no `.` after it should work.

Comment: @TemporalWolf that's why I check the entire list, not just a single entry. But maybe this answer could be improved.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, I was misreading. I don't think it's a list of separate lists, I think the terms are directly mixed.

Comment: @TemporalWolf it would help if I didn't have a typo... fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working answer:

```
>>> s
['0.00', '0.000', '874.80', '10.000', '1,234.56', '29.461,24', '20.919,000', '0,00', '0,000', '372,13', '11,000']
>>> l = []
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> for x in s:
        r = re.search(r'(\d+)[.,](\d+)[.,]?(\d*)', x)
        if r:
            if r.group(3):
                l.append('{0}{1}.{2}'.format(*r.groups()))
            elif r.group(2):
                l.append('{0}.{1}'.format(*r.groups()))
            else:
                l.append('{}'.format(*r.groups()))


>>> l
['0.00', '0.000', '874.80', '10.000', '1234.56', '29461.24', '20919.000', '0.00', '0.000', '372.13', '11.000']
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a "pure" regex solution, I came up with the solution below. Note, users are not perfect and are rarely as rigorous in data entry as we'd like, so prior solutions that relied on strict number groupings didn't work for my use case. The solution here works for "fuzzy" entries like "1,000000.0". Of course, the trade-off is that there is the potential for ambiguous entries by the user. The solution below offers a relatively US-centric resolution in the case of ambiguity. I'm no regex expert so I am sure there is a more elegant solution to do this (dm me if this could be improved).

```
def castToFloat( txt ):
    adjText = re.sub(r",(?=\d{3},\d{3})|(?<=\d,\d{3}),|(?<=\d),(?=\d{3,},)|(?<=\d),(?=\d{3}\.)", "", txt) #remove groupings of three comma separated numbers
    adjText = re.sub(r"\.(?=\d{3}\.\d{3})|(?<=\d\.\d{3})\.|(?<=\d)\.(?=\d{3,},)", "", adjText) #remove groupings of three decimal separated numbers 
    return float( re.sub(r"(?<=[0]),(?=\d{1,}\b)|,(?=\d{1,2}\b)|(?<=\d{3}),(?=\d{1,}\b)", ".", adjText).replace( ",", "" ) )
```

Here are my test cases:

- Entry '1,000,000' | Float output : 1000000.0
- Entry '1000,000.0' | Float output : 1000000.0
- Entry '1,000000.0' | Float output : 1000000.0
- Entry '1,000,000.00' | Float output : 1000000.0
- Entry '1,000,000.0' | Float output : 1000000.0
- Entry '1,345,265.4' | Float output : 1345265.4
- Entry '1,234' | Float output : 1234.0
- Entry '1,334.99' | Float output : 1334.99
- Entry '334.99' | Float output : 334.99
- Entry '1.000.000' | Float output : 1000000.0
- Entry '1.000000,00' | Float output : 1000000.0
- Entry '1000.000,00' | Float output : 1000000.0
- Entry '1000000,00' | Float output : 1000000.0
- Entry '3432.33' | Float output : 3432.33
- Entry '3,432.33' | Float output : 3432.33
- Entry '432,44' | Float output : 432.44
- Entry '0,934' | Float output : 0.934
- Entry '0.934' | Float output : 0.934
- Entry '1.234,4567' | Float output : 1234.4567
- Entry '1,000.00' | Float output : 1000.0

---

Ambiguous Entries:

- Entry '1000,000' | Float output : 1000.0
- Entry '1000.000' | Float output : 1000.0
- Entry '2.431' | Float output : 2.431
- Entry '2,431' | Float output : 2431.0
- Entry '2,435555' | Float output : 2435555.0

Answer (score 0):

This is my proposed solutions which works assuming that there are only 2 numbers after the decimal sign. Code can be optimized, but works as an initial quick and dirty solution.

```
us_nodec1 = "1,000,000"
us_nodec2 = "1,234"
us_dec = "1,334.99"
us_dec1 = "334.99"
eu_nodec1 = "1.000.000"
eu_nodec2 = "2.431"
eu_dec = "3,432.33"
eu_dec1 = "432,44"

def fix_nr_format(string):
    comma_counts = string.count(',')
    point_counts = string.count('.')
    comma_splits = string.split(',')
    point_splits = string.split('.')
    if comma_splits.__len__() > 1:
        if comma_splits[-1].__len__() > 2:
            string = string.replace(',', '')
        elif comma_splits[-1].__len__() == 2:
            if not string.__contains__('.'):
                string = string.replace(',', '.')
            else:
                string = string.replace('.', '', point_counts-1)
    if point_splits.__len__() > 1:
        if point_splits[-1].__len__() > 2:
            string = string.replace('.', '')
        elif point_splits[-1].__len__() == 2:
            if not string.__contains__(','):
                pass
            else:
                string.replace(',', '', comma_counts-1)
    return float(string)
print(fix_nr_format(eu_dec))
print(fix_nr_format(eu_dec1))
print(fix_nr_format(eu_nodec1))
print(fix_nr_format(eu_nodec2))
print(fix_nr_format(us_nodec1))
print(fix_nr_format(us_nodec2))
print(fix_nr_format(us_dec))
print(fix_nr_format(us_dec1))
3432.33
432.44
1000000.0
2431.0
1000000.0
1234.0
1334.99
334.99
```